# How is the green box for showing reputation gained after last view of reputation tab useful?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-tab

I always see the box as I mentioned in the title, I want to know why it's useful?, see the following image:

[image: Image of mine]

My questions:

- why is that needed?
- since there is a "+" sign there, asking what happens if you lose reputation after the latest view of SO, will the box say "-" instead, will the box turn red?

Comment: Much more important question: Why is your red circle ain't drawn freehand - don't you have a soul? ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix Lol, i use Paint, and made a box, and make a text by typing :-), :D

Comment: it is the reputation gain since the last time you clicked the reputation tab in your profile. It is useful as SO thrives on the gammification of sharing knowledge. Seeing no green box with +42 should trigger users to contribute so they gain more rep and with that privileges. The box will not turn red when you got negative gain. It is all about positive reinforcement.

Comment: @iLuvLogix the most important question is why isn't it a proper red!

Comment: Damn MS-Paint is sucking the life-force out of every red line it can find - boxes, circles and even lines nowadays ;)

Comment: @Script47 : Just noticed that - how dare you not to use #FF0000 !!!! ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix Well, got it :D, i only can use that because i do not have Photoshop or something...

Comment: @Script47 Actually, i randomly did a color

Comment: gimp it like a pro ;)

Comment: @rene You could write an answer with that well explained comment ;)

Comment: Thou your profile pic of a free-hand snail proofs that your soul is not completety lost to geometric highlighting ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix I let gnat find a duplicate ..